# Is there a way to read the exact values on a colormap "image"?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colormap

So I have a *.jpg image and it basically represents a 2D colormap with a colorbar beside it that shows the range of values on the map (just imagine you make a filled 2-D contour plot with MATLAB and take a screenshot from it; something like that!). I was wondering if there is a way to read the exact values (or at least values that are closed to the exact values) from this colormap, based on the numbers on its colorbar? I have also attached the image that I'm talking about:

[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just do the same as a human would do. Take the colour and see which value belongs to it.

Of course you are limited to the resolution of your colour map.

Comment: Well thanks Mr. Genius haha! But I was looking for an image processing tool that might exist out there. The image I attached is a pretty simple one. If you have a complex color map then it can be really difficult to only rely on your human eyes! :)

Comment: @Antonio Maybe you should improve your question if you want to know more then yes or no.  You can do this with any image processing library out there. but there is no one solves them all though. the tricky part is to read the legend. interpreting the map itself is trivial